# VB.Net Visual basic Adding a custom event in the Webbrowser control that calls a routine in the main application

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create and call a custom event in the webbrowser control and everything that I've tried to do causes one error or another when the webpage executes the code.  What I'm doing is adding a button on each row of a table to facilitate removing that row.  However, the master list of data is in the application.  When the script in the web page executes, I need to update the master list in the application.  My thoughts were to call a custom event that will be fired in my application where I can do everything that I need to do.  I just can't make this work.  here are more details of what I have right now.  Here is the html code for a given row:

```
Dim M As String = "</TD><TD>"
RetStr.Append("<TR ID='" & Me.Manifest & "' name='" & Me.Manifest & "'>")
RetStr.Append("<TD>").Append(CompanyID).Append(M).Append(CompanyName).Append(M)
RetStr.Append(ContactName).Append(M).Append(Address1).Append(M).Append(Address2)
RetStr.Append(M).Append(City).Append(M).Append(State).Append(M)
RetStr.Append(Zip).Append(M).Append(Phone).Append("</TD>")
RetStr.Append("<TD><button onclick='deleteRow(""" & Me.Manifest & """)'>Remove</button></TD>")
Return Replace(RetStr.ToString(), "<TD></TD>", "<TD>&nbsp;</TD>")
```

Here is the code that is in the function:

```
Dim HTMLOut As New List(Of String)
HTMLOut.Add("<HEAD>")
HTMLOut.Add("  <SCRIPT language=""VBScript"">")
HTMLOut.Add("    Function deleteRow(rowid)")
HTMLOut.Add("      set row = document.getElementById(rowid)")
HTMLOut.Add("      row.parentNode.removeChild(row)")
HTMLOut.Add("      dispatchEvent(Row)")
HTMLOut.Add("    End Function")
HTMLOut.Add("  </SCRIPT>")
HTMLOut.Add("</HEAD>")
HTMLOut.Add("<BODY>")
HTMLOut.Add("  <TABLE border='1' style='font-size:12;' NAME='Table' ID='TABLE'>")
```

Here is the code that I have in the application:

```
Private Sub WB_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As 
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WB.DocumentCompleted
    WB.Document.AttachEventHandler("UpdateList", New EventHandler(
                                   Function(ByVal s As Object, ByVal k As EventArgs)
                                       MsgBox("BOO")
                                       Return True
                                   End Function))
End Sub
```

Any help in any direction, even if it means I need to change how I'm doing all of this, is very welcomed!  There is more code then this, it's stripped down to what is needed to convey what I'm doing.  I know I'm missing something, I just can't figure out what it is.  The end goal is to update the master list in the application hosting the web browser; ideas suggestions and comments are always welcome.  As a side note, I'm using the web browser control because the final part of the process is to create a file and sftp it to the vender (the application will do this), and print the report.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I needed to create a class object, with the comvisible attribute set and add this to the objectForScripting property of the web browser control.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
<ComVisible(True)> Public Class WBClassCode
    Public Sub UpdateStuff(ByVal Data)
        'My code goes here... called from the web page.
        MsgBox("boo")
    End Sub
End Class
```